# VSCode extension to auto generate C docstring?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, python-sphinx, vscode-extensions

I'm starting to get into more advanced codding practices and came across the need to create full documentations for my libraries which I write in C in the VSCode IDE and in an effort to try and same time I'm looking for a way to auto generate C Sphinx style docstring in VSCode now there is a lot of support to do that for python as it seems but can't find anything for autogen C sphinx docsting

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a Doxygen extension, IDK if it's what you need. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen

Comment: I also like codding

Comment: @anastaciu Yes exactly what I was looking for thanks you! please post this an an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Doxygen extension, I quite like it, it's very good and easy to use:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen